Nuxt -> Directory Structure -> Server getting Invalid environment configuration error when npm run build
I had a hello.ts file under the server folder.
When running npm run dev, it is able to load http://localhost:3000/api/hello.
However, when running npm run build, it returns the following error:
{ 
  "url": "/api/hello", 
  "statusCode": 500, 
  "statusMessage": "", 
  "message": "Invalid environment configuration", 
  "stack": ""
} 

I expected that when npm run build, the result would be the same as npm run dev.
Is there any solution that might be useful?

Is it a brand new Nuxt project? We cannot know your settings so far. Also, what's inside of the file?

Hi @kissu, I am referring this documentation. https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/directory-structure/server
And my server folder structure is
-| server/
---| api/
-----| hello.ts      # /api/hello

Yes. This does not answer my questions tho. Consider updating your question rather.

May i know what means for brand new Nuxt project? What info or file that need to provide?

"is it a new project that you created with nothing custom in it?" is another way of formulating the question.

I customized a template to become a new project. The original template actually dont have server folder. Server folder added by myself.

Do you maybe have a public github repo?

I found the root cause to be nuxt.config.ts.
Before:
runtimeConfig: {
  appBaseurl: ""
},

After:
runtimeConfig: {
  appBaseurl: process.env.NUXT_APP_BASEURL
},


This is not exactly the way to go but can work indeed.
